# Create a multidimensional array from array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert an associative array from a Drupal database into a multidimensional array that I can encode into json.

I start with:

```
$notifications =`

    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rfp_id] => RFP-013-2014(C)
            [notification_type] => due_date
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rfp_id] => RFP-013-2014(C)
            [notification_type] => changes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [rfp_id] => RFP-013-2014(C)
            [notification_type] => due_date
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [rfp_id] => RFP-014-2014(C)
            [notification_type] => due_date
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [rfp_id] => RFP-014-2014(C)
            [notification_type] => changes
        )
    )
```

I would like to group by the rfp_id field and end up with something like:

```
Array (
  [0]=> Array (
    ["rfp_id"]=>"RFP-014-2014"
    ["notification_type"]=>
    Array (
      [0]=> "date_due"
      [1]=> "changes"
    )
  )
)
```

How would I loop through this array to create this?

Comment: Basically it's the same like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557428/custom-formatted-json-from-mysql-pdo-for-use-in-nvd3-js/25557722

Comment: What efforts have you made to do this?

Comment: @MikeBrant I tried a couple different options for looping through the array.  The closest I got was each notification_type as an array rather than all of the notification_type as one array.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois no its not the same.  I need to group by one of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no change in the dimensionality of your array, it's just restructured. You could do it like this:

```
foreach ($notifications as $notification)
{
  $rfp_id = $notification['rfp_id'];
  $newArray[$rfp_id]['rfp_id'] = $rfp_id;
  $newArray[$rfp_id]['notification_type'][] = $notification['notification_type'];
} 
echo '<pre>'.print_r($newArray,TRUE).'</pre>';
```

As you can see i've done it slightly different as specified, just because it is easier. If you want numeric keys you could do:

```
$newArray = array_values($newArray);
```

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: Nope, I was going to post the same.  Creating array indexes on the fly regardless of whether the higher level exists or even if the array exixts does not generate a notice.

Comment: Once I changed print_f to print_r this wired perfectly.  Once I called array_values I got exactly the output that I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$result = array();

foreach ($notifications as $key => $note) {
    $result[$note['rfp_id']]['rfp_id'] = $note['rfp_id'];
    $result[$note['rfp_id']]['notification_type'][] = $note['notification_type'];

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Should do it. Since you're inserting into the database right after I assume you don't need to reset the keys to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

something like this would work:

$array = array();

```
//loop over the array
foreach($notifications as $row){
    //if this rfp id doesn't exist, add it
    if(!isset($array[$row['rfp_id']])){
        //add the first entry in the array
        $array[$row['rfp_id']] = array(
                'rfp_id'=>$row['rfp_id'],
                'notification_type'=>array(
                    $row['notification_type']
                )
            );
    } else {
        //rfp_id exists, so just append the notification type
        $array[$row['rfp_id']]['notification_type'][] = $row['notification_type'];
    }
}
//get just the values to reset the first level keys to numeric.
$array = array_values($array);

//display the array
echo '<pre>'.print_r($array,true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Maybe add something like `foreach ($array as &$entry) { $entry["notification_type"] = array_unique($entry["notification_type"]);
}` after `array_values` to get rid of duplicated notification_types.